# How do I prevent opening a href url when clicking included checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a object (stores, buildings, etc.) box, surrounded by a href link to the objects detail page. Inside this box, is object information and a checkbox for bookmarking that object.

So, when clicking the checkbox, the object shall be bookmarked (prevent a href click). When clicking anywhere else in that box, the detail page shall open.

simplyfied example:

```
$(".func_prevent").click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest('a').preventDefault();
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/details.php">
   <div class="box bg-image">
      <p>My Object title</p>
      <p>my text</p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" class="func_prevent" name="bookmark"> bookmark object</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

But this doesn't work. The detail page still opens, when clicking the checkbox...

Any suggestions on this??

Comment: Have you tried identifying the href tag with a class or ID instead of closest. preventDefault() should work.

Comment: Are you sure you want to wrap the `<a>` around the entire thing? Would make more sense to me to just link the title. Would avoid this problem too.

Comment: Inputs inside links are not permitted by HTML...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `e.stopPropagation();` instead of `$(this).closest('a').preventDefault();`

Comment: I just noticed that my problem seems to be firefox specific. Your code runs in chrome, but fails in firefox... https://jsfiddle.net/svayn7jL/7/

Comment: Yes you are right, it doesn't work in firefox. Best solution is that you shouldn't insert checkbox inside anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".func_prevent").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

the "return false" calls ".preventDefault()" and ".stopPropagation()" and not ".stopImmediatePropagation()". Therefore it stops the event bubbling.

You could also try hooking on to the class or id if you don't want to affect other links.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
$("a").on('click', '.func_prevent', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/vh4jtrg3/14/

Comment: But then the link won't be opened, when clicking outside the checkbox...